# Django-imagekit is crashing system when used in API

Tags: django, imagekit, django-imagekit

I am utilizing Imagekit to resize some images and export 3 different variations in a JSON format for an api call:

```
'image': k.thumbnail_large.url if k.image else '',                                                                                                                                   
'thumb_med': k.thumbnail_medium.url if k.image else '',
'icon': k.thumbnail_icon.url if k.image else '',
```

Problem is that on my non-beefy virtualized server of 512mb of RAM, I am crashing the Django application server when it tries to resize over 50 images * 3.

How do I go about priming/preprocessing these with over 500 images now entered into the CMS?

Comment: "Crashing" how?  Do you have details like a stack trace?

Comment: No stack trace.  It would just consume all the resources.  I resolved the issue though:  I changed it from `ImageSpec` to `ProcessedImageField(null=True,editable=False,blank=True)`.  I also modified the `save()` of the model to: `self.thumbnail_medium.save(os.path.basename(self.image.name), self.image, save=False)` and the same for the large and icon, respectfully.